# How do i use SPOOL in DataGrip?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, datagrip

I am trying to use `spool` in DataGrip but it appears that it doesn't work. It doesn't even create an empty file.

When I use the same file in SqlDeveloper, it works.

[image: Here is the command]

When i run the script, it only runs the `SELECT` and shows me the 'Instruction' table. Is there some hidden setting i have to switch or DataGrip doens't support `spool`

Comment: SQL Puls script execution is not supported yet. Please upvote for this feature request so that it can get more attention:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-17941/Support-oracle-sql-plus-script-execution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SPOOL` is a [command supported by Oracle client applications](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlqr/SQL-Plus-Commands.html#GUID-688EBA31-35DB-42A6-A0A1-DA1F5EA45CF3) such as SQL*Plus, SQL Developer and SQLCl and runs on the client and not in the database.

It is **NOT** an SQL statement and is not supported by Oracle databases (only by some clients used to talk to Oracle databases).

> Is there some hidden setting I have to switch or DataGrip doesn't support `spool`

There is no "hidden switch"; it is not an SQL statement and is not supported by the database or by clients that do not support SQL*Plus commands.

Comment: So there is absolutely no way of making it work on DataGrip? I am thinking that such a big company would make something to make something simple like this work.

Comment: @Iustin You may be able to ask the question "How can I get DataGrip to write the console output to a file instead (or, as well as) of the screen?" and someone might be able to give you an answer (or you can just read the DataGrip documentation) but for the question as asked, "Does DataGrip support the SQL\*Plus `SPOOL` command?", the answer is No.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. I changed the dialect of the file to SQL Plus and i got the syntax highlighting and i thought its all good with DataGrip but apparently not :( back to SQLDeveloper